# SSL Configuration on Linux[Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)]

Tags: redhat, ssl-certificate

My Linux distro : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
Configuring ssl on this software
Kibana-4.3.0-linux-x64

I am trying to configure ssl on kibana.
 
The steps I followed:

1. Generated private key

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out privatekey.key 2048
   ```

   The above command created a file names `privatekey.key` .
2. Genrated CSR

   ```
   openssl req -new -key privatekey.key -out linux.csr
   ```

   Entered the details this csr asked. and then `linux.csr` file was created.
3. I submitted this linux.csr to my organization and I was issued a certificate certnew.cer
   The certificate contents were like:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
4. Now `kibana-4.3.0-linux-x64` folder was present on home path of linux machine
   I made the following changes to `kibana.yml` file

   ```
   ssl.server..cert : /home/.../certnew.cer
   ssl.server.key : /home/.../privatekey.key
   ```
5. Now, I start kibana and get the following log:-
   In the log it says:

   ```
   log [17:49:38.853] [info][status][plugin:kibana] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:38.925] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch
   log [17:49:38.965] [info][status][plugin:kbn_vislib_vis_types] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:38.977] [info][status][plugin:markdown_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:38.994] [info][status][plugin:metric_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:39.002] [info][status][plugin:spyModes] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:39.009] [info][status][plugin:elasticsearch] Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready
   log [17:49:39.013] [info][status][plugin:statusPage] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:39.021] [info][status][plugin:table_vis] Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready
   log [17:49:39.046] [info][listening] Server running at https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8601
   ```

In the Browser when I try to open https://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8601. It runs but it is specified as Not secure and https is crossed in red colour.
Can anybody help me what steps I am missing ?

What I understand is that I need to add ssl certificate [`certnew.cer`] or maybe `privatekey[privatekey.key]` to linux trusted list which I suppose. Can anybody help me with that or point me to a link

Answer (score 0):

The certificate of your server is not trusted by a AC which is recognized by your browser.

You can add the AC certificate which has emitted the certificate of your kibana in your browser like this, it depends of your browser.

- [For Ie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750534.aspx)
- [For Firefox](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/firefox-adding-trusted-ca/)

Answer (score 0):

TLS certificates are issued for hostnames, not for IP addresses. Use the appropriate hostname in your URL.